# Detect a specific website my WebBrowser navigated to

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I'm using a `WebBrowser Control` on a WPF application that opens a website with a form for the user to fill and submit. After submitting, it redirects to another page after 10 secs, `www.google.com` for example.

Is there a way to detect when the `WebBrowser` has opened `www.google.com`?

Comment: Have you tried using the `DocumentCompleted` event?

Comment: Or may be you mean 'Navigated' event ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx

Comment: @Jasper, it may need to be a combination of those events. The `Navigated` event may fire during the redirect, but if the OP wants to know when `www.google.com` has been loaded, they are going to need to consume the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: thanks for the answers i will try what you guys sugested

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when the WebBrowser has opened your site name in `webbrowser_LoadCompleted` event,try this:

```
void webbrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocument doc =( mshtml.HTMLDocument) s.Document;
    if (doc.parentWindow.window.location.host == "www.google.com")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you navigated to google");
    }
}
```